# Owner changed to _apt systemd-journal

Tags: debian, permissions, chown

For some unknown, mysterious reasons, most of the folders on my debian have been switched from root:root to _apt:systemd-journal

```
arthur@debian:~$ ls -la /data/tera_4/Content/
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 8 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Feb 16  2021  .
drwxrwxr-x 6 _apt systemd-journal 4096 May  5  2021  ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Oct 22  2020  A
drwxrwxr-x 2 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Jun 28  2020  B
drwxrwxr-x 6 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Jun  2  2020  C
drwxrwxr-x 5 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Jun 28  2020  D
drwxrwxr-x 6 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Feb 18  2021  E
drwxrwxr-x 8 _apt systemd-journal 4096 Aug 22  2020  F
```

Any idea what could cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats weird it could come from a misconfigured script maybe, you should look into your history file `~/.bash_history`, your logs files `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log`, and `/var/log/apt/history.log` and check for unauthorized access maybe your system was comprimised ( user account )